# Find the longest walk that covers the most number of x_i

Tags: python-3.x, tree, sparse-matrix

I am currently trying to implement an algorithm that shares many similarities with the matrix-to-tree algorithm (I found these 2 threads pretty relevant....https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71466/matrix-to-tree-algorithm, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-ancestor-matrix/), although after converting from the matrix to tree, the parent nodes could have multiple children nodes (rather than only two).

The problem can be described very simply using the data matrix below

```
          x_1  x_2  x_3  (x_1, x_2)  (x_1, x_3)  (x_2, x_3)   (X,Y) 
x_1        0    1    1       0            0           0         1 
x_2        0    0    1       0            1           0         0 
x_3        1    0    0       1            0           0         1
(x_1, x_2) 0    0    1       0            0           0         0
(x_1, x_3) 0    1    0       0            0           0         1
(x_2, x_3) 1    0    0       0            0           0         1
```

**Problem.** Assume the root node of the tree can *only* start with elements that have `1` in the last column `(X,Y)` of the matrix. Translate the matrix above into a tree (or a tree-like algorithm). Then find `one` sequence (i.e. `one` path of the tree) that includes *the most* number of `x_i` covered, based on the given matrix (for example, in this case, if we start with `x_1`, then the path the algo should find is: `x_1 -> x_2 -> x_3`. If we start with x_3, we can have `x_3 -> (x_1, x_2)`. Both have all `x_1, x_2, x_3` covered). Note that `x_i -> x_j` if and only if the element `[x_i, x_j] = 1` in the matrix.

**Question.** How can I tackle this problem with Python `3.x`'s version?

Comment: How far have you gotten on what is very, very clearly your homework assignment? Which part is not working?

Comment: @CJR: It's not a homework assignment Sir. I haven't figured out how to translate from a matrix into a tree and search for the path that contains the most number of variables. The fact that there could be multiple trees, as the root node is not static, made this problem quite challenging to me. Not sure how come you find it simple?

PS: I'm trying to modify this code, and I try to figure out how to keep track of number of variables that have occurred in a particular path. https://www.techiedelight.com/construct-binary-tree-ancestor-matrix/

Comment: Could anyone help me with the step on building out the trees, based on the given binary matrix?